# Square brackets functioning in expression as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I am looking for strings that contain this string `[management]`

Here is a model of scenario:

```
create table #test (st varchar(200))
insert into #test
values 
('hello'),
('hello management'),
('hello [management]'),
('hello [management] blah'),
('hello [management rev] blah');

select * from #test where st like '%\[management]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

The above finds what I expect but why does the following not find the same strings?

```
select * from #test where st like '%[[]management[]]%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question! Instictly it feels like %[[]text[]]% should resolve to:

*ANYTHING*[text]*ANYTHING*.

But it doesn't.  Because ], unlike [, doesn't start a pattern search it does not need escaping. Use %[[]text]% instead.

For more detail see the "Using Wildcard Characters As Literals" section on the [MSDN Like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) page.

Comment: ok - thanks - but even if ] does not start a pattern search (so is already a literal?) what is the harm in putting square brackets around it?! Is this regex 'hello' not equivalent to 'hel[l]o'?

Comment: I really wanted to add a clever paragraph answering just that question, but despite my best efforts I couldn't figure it out.  My problem is not I'm not sure what [] on it's own means.  LIKE '%[]%' does not match anything (either from your sample records or empty strings).  I suspect []] resolves to [] with an additional ].  The [] part prevents any matches.

Comment: I think @t-clausen.dk answers addresses this.  He states that [] asks SQL to match nothing, which of course cannot be done.

Answer (score 4):

You should only escape the start bracket like this:

```
DECLARE @t table(x varchar(100))
INSERT @t 
SELECT '[management]'

SELECT * from @t where x like '%[[]management]%'
```

EDIT:

Once you put in '[]]', the *like* expect to find a character that matches nothing. '[xy]]' would demand a list of characters ('x' or 'y') to be in that position, '[]]' would result in an empty list of characters to be in that position, making the match impossible.

Comment: thanks - do you have a reference for me so I can read up what is going on - this is really counter-intuitive!

Comment: (hope you do not mind - you got to the answer first but he needs the points and gave a nice explanation)